# How to formalize "Division by zero" in a proof about groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Assume $K \subseteq H \subseteq G$ are groups. We want to show that if $[G:K]$ is finite then so are $[G:H]$ and $[H:K]$ and vice versa.

We know from the proof of Lagrange's theorem that $|G| = [G:K]|K|$ and  that $|H| = [H:K]|K|$ and that $|G|=[G:H]|H|$ (even for infinite groups)

So $[G:H]|H| = [G:K]|K| \iff [G:H][H:K]|K| = [G:K]|K| \iff [G:H][H:K] = [G:K]$

So if $[G:K]$ is finite so are $[G:H]$ and $[H:K]$

This proof works if the order of $K$ is finite, but it's very problematic if it's infinite, i want to know if it's possible to formalize the last step or if this proof remains fallacious for infinite groups no matter what (I know the result is correct)

Comment: You say, if $[G:K]$ is infinite, then so are $[G:H]$ and $[H:K]$, but don’t we only know that at least one of them is? That’s all we need anyway.

Comment: I had a typo my appologies

Comment: For example, $G$ could be multiplicative group of non-zero rationals, $H$ could be $\{1,-1\}$ and $K$ could be trivial. That gives $2$ times infinity equals infinity.

Comment: The point is, we want to show they are finite

Comment: You can prove, set-theoretically, if $G/H$ means the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$, that there’s a good bijection between $(G/H)\times H$ and $G$. It follows that if either $G/H$ or $H$ is infinite, then the cardinality of $G$ is the max of the cardinalities of $G/H$ and $H$. Your proof will probably use Axiom of Choice.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that the proof does not work if $K$ is infinite. However, the result still holds in that case. Argue in terms of cosets as in the following proof sketch:

$G$ is the disjoint union of the $|G:H|$ cosets of $H$.

Each coset of $H$ is the disjoint union of $|H:K|$ cosets of $K$.

Each coset of $K$ is contained in exactly one coset of $H$.

The total number of cosets of $K$ is $|G:K|$. From the above, it should be clear that we must have $|G:K| = |G:H||H:K|$, where the LHS is finite if and only if both factors on the RHS are finite.